# Defined or undefined limit?

Tags: limits

I'm having trouble finding what the value of $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \sqrt{1-x}$ is.

Is it zero, or is it undefined? I asked in another forum as well, and received different opinions.. I am very confused.

Comment: When x is more than 1 what will the expression under the root be ?  Negative ?  Then you have your answer.

Comment: I know, but the fact that you can actually insert 1 as x without making any obvious mistakes like dividing by zero made me unsure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is undefined.

The function $x\mapsto \sqrt{1-x}$ is only defined for $1-x>0$, so only for $x<1$.

In your case, the limit only takes undefined values, since it is a limit when $x$ is **decreasing** to $1$.

The limit $$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\sqrt{1-x}$$
on the other hand *does* exist and is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the square root $\sqrt{1-x}$ is meaningless for all $x > 1$. So, in particular, the limit $\lim_{x \to 1+}\sqrt{1-x}$ does not exist at all.

Comment: It exists in the sense of taking a limit along a contour in $\mathbb{C}$, though, does it not?

Comment: @PatrickStevens But then you need to define which branch of the square root you are taking.